# How to disable i18n language dropdown in node form?

Tags: forms, i18n-l10n

I'ld like to prevent editors from changing the language of a node. Role check works. But I how to disable the language field? Why doesn't it work like any other form field? How is this field placed there? Where can I alter it? This doesn't work:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $user;
    $editor = in_array('editor', $user->roles) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $node_edit = isset($form['#node_edit_form']) && $form['#node_edit_form'] ? TRUE : FALSE;

    if ($node_edit && $editor) {
        $form['language']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
        $form['language']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the administrator theme? I recommend you register a theme for this form in Theme Registry, then do the configuration. what you are trying to do is not working in administrator theme.

Comment: How about changing your module's weight so it runs later.

Comment: @Drupalist - Seven is admin theme. Why wouldn't that work in my admin theme?

Comment: @J.Reynolds - Because the i18n also is added later to the form?

Comment: @koivo That is what I suspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the i18n dropdown is attached to the node form afterwards. For now I simply `unset($form['#after_build'][0])` where `_i18n_node_form_node_form_alter` is called. Unsetting it hides all other available languages from the dropdown making it impossible to change it. To me that seems fine. If there's a more appropriate way to do this, please let me know.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $user;
    $editor = in_array('editor', $user->roles) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    if (isset($form['#node_edit_form']) && $form['#node_edit_form'] == TRUE && $editor) {
        unset($form['#after_build'][0]);
    }
}
```

---

Finally I did it like @J.Reynolds suggested with [`hook_module_implements_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to ensure that my module runs after Locale module

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $user;
    $editor = in_array('editor', $user->roles) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $node_edit = isset($form['#node_edit_form']) && $form['#node_edit_form'] ? TRUE : FALSE;

    if ($node_edit && $editor) {
        $form['language']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
    }
}

function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
    if ($hook == 'form_alter') {
        $module = 'MYMODULE';
        // store
        $group = array($module => $implementations[$module]);
        // unset
        unset($implementations[$module]);
        // add to the end
        $implementations = $implementations + $group;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just ran your code from your question and it worked fine by me. I then checked my module's weight and it ran after locale. I then changed my module's weight so that it ran before local, and now I experienced your issue. So the answer is simply to change your module's weight so that it runs after locale. Use hook_module_implements_alter, and unset your module's key, then just add it to the end of the array.

Comment: @J.Reynolds - Thanks a lot again! Added it to my answer

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily by disabling multi language from your content type.

For example admin/structure/types/manage/YOURCONTENTTYPE

Go to publising option 
and disable the multilanguage

[image]

Save the content type 
That's it.